# **StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version** in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am trying to execute a tensorflow script on my local computer. But the following warning appears. It would be really helpful if someone can specify what the common cause for this warning is.

```
2020-10-26 14:04:34.690753: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2020-10-26 14:04:34.707717: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7fadab4339f0 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-10-26 14:04:34.707751: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
```

I tried tracing my code and this is the line that gives the error :

```
model = load_model(MODEL_PATH)
```

and I import `load_model` using

```
from keras.models import load_model
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for the above warning is the `Tensorflow` library is not optimized for your particular architecture which `Tensorflow` was originally compiled on different architecture machine.
You can ignore this warning but you won't be getting maximum performance from the library.

To fix this warning and get maximum performance, you need to build `Tensorflow` on your machine.

You can follow [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source) documentation to build Tensorflow from source for **Linux and macOS** for **Windows** you can follow [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows) documentation.